# SSH using Python Paramiko: How to detect SSH Server responding with string on successful connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

When I connect to my Ubuntu server via SSH using the terminal, it sometimes return a certain string then closes the connection.

```
$ ssh hello@my.server.com -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
container not found
Connection to 123.10.10.231 closed.
Connection to my.server.com closed.
```

Using `paramiko` in my Python script to connect to this server, how do I detect when this is happening?

Currently I'm doing the following to make the connection:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
    
ssh.connect("my.server.com", 22, userfoo, key_filename="/home/gameveloster/.ssh/id_ed25519")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print(stdout.readlines(), stderr.readlines())
```

and getting the following output even when the server is not closing the SSH connection immediately on connecting.

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
["Error: Your SSH client doesn't support PTY\n"] []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server seems to need terminal to print that message.

In general, it's not a good idea to enable terminal emulation, when automating commands. But if you need that message, you will probably have to do it. Use `get_pty` parameter of `SSHClient.exec_command`:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls', get_pty=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can put your code inside `try` and `except` block -

```
try:
    ssh.connect("my.server.com", 22, userfoo, key_filename="/home/gameveloster/.ssh/id_ed25519")
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException:
    # catch the exception
```

And then in `ssh` command pass the `T` parameter -

```
ssh -T hello@my.server.com -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```